# JPA + Hibernate. Compatible column definition for Oracle and SQL Server numeric field

Tags: sql-server, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I need to create an entity that works with preexistent tables in Oracle and MS SQL Server.

In Oracle there is a field defined as `my_num_field  number(15)` while in MS SQL Server the equivalent field is `my_num_field numeric(15)`.
The column definition in my entity is:

```
@Column(name="my_num_field")
Long myNumField;
```

This works in Oracle but with SQL Server the Hibernate database schema validation fails:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: 
wrong column type encountered in column [my_num_field] in table [my_table]; 
found [numeric (Types #NUMERIC)], but expecting [bigint (Types#BIGINT)]
```

If I specify the columnDefinition as numeric, it works for SQL Server

```
@Column(name="my_num_field", columnDefinition="numeric")
Long myNumField;
```

But now the Hibernate database schema validation for Oracle fails:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation:
wrong column type encountered in column [my_num_field] in table [my_table];
found [number (Types#DECIMAL)], but expecting [numeric (Types#BIGINT)]
```

I'm Using Hibernate 5 as my JPA provider.
And my databases are Oracle 10g and SQL Server 2014

Is there any way to define the column in my entity so it works in both databases or if that's not possible, what other options do I have?